# Select distinct from multiple fields using sql & a Date_Time col

Tags: sql, group-by, union, distinct

I have a table that records when a user logs in.
I want to find all the users that have logged in within the last year.

So, simplified I have

```
|  Client_ID  |  DateLoggedIn  |
|      1      |    05/02/10    |
|      2      |    14/05/11    |
|      1      |    26/05/11    |
|      3      |    18/04/10    |
|      2      |    21/12/11    |
```

I'm trying to return the ClientID with the most recent date
eg:

```
|  Client_ID  |  DateLoggedIn  |
|      1      |    26/05/11    |
|      2      |    21/12/11    |
|      3      |    18/04/10    |
```

I have tried using Group By and tried the UNION join, but I think I'm doing something wrong...

All help gratefully received !!!

Thanks folks  :)

Comment: Given some of the different answers I think you need to be a bit clearer in the question . ie is it "all the users" or "ClientID with the most recent date" and is the second set of data the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the other Mark:

```
select Client_ID, max(DateLoggedIn)
from table
where DateLoggedIn > X /* X = one year ago - derivation will be DB-dependant */
group by Client_ID
order by max(DateLoggedIn) desc
```

Comment: This is the droid I was looking for !!
Thanks a lot to all you guys who spent time looking at this for me, it really is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just for completeness, here's the code I used in the end  (I'm using SQL Server 2008)


SELECT Client_ID, MAX(DateLoggedIn)

FROM Login_Tracking

WHERE DateLoggedIn > DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())

GROUP BY Client_ID

ORDER BY max(DateLoggedIn) DESC

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which RDBMS you're using:

```
Select top 1 client_ID
From table
order by DateLoggedIn desc
```

or:

```
SELECT client 
FROM ( SELECT client_ID, 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateLoggedIn DESC) rank
       FROM table ) 
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but it didn't help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple groupby of an aggregate function and use having to limit the results

If X is the date you want to fileter by then

```
select Client_ID, max(DateLoggedIn)
    from table
    group by Client_ID
    having  max(DateLoggedIn) > X
```

Setting X I think depends on the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Client_ID, DateLoggedIn from TableName
GROUP BY Client_ID
Order By DateLoggedIn DESC
```

Comment: OP wants just the one entry for a Client_ID

Comment: @Mark As per Table 2 in the Question, DateLoggedIn  is Maximum date per Client

Comment: That is what he wants to get not what he is selecting from